# How can I check if one file is newer than another in Git?

Tags: git

I have 2 files both residing in the same git repo. There is a dependency between these files.
In my CI/CD pipeline, I have a step to do some build checks. Here, I would like to add a check to assert that the git timestamp of the 2nd file is equal or newer than the 1st.
Is there any standard functionality for this ?

The actual use-case comes from K8S:
The first file is the source of some (sealed) secret. The second file is created from that through a script which takes user input (password) as result, the 2nd file just contains some large unreadable ASCII string. Only the 2nd file is used in K8S, so forgetting to update that one, means that the change is not taken in.

thx, M

Comment: You can get each file's timestamp with `git log -1 --pretty="%ad" -- path/to/file`.

Comment: Why don't you instead of having a build step that checks the second file is up to date have a step which creates the second file from the first? You avoid trying to use git for something which it was not made for. Even if you need both files in the repo it would still be better to validate the second file by generating it again and see if the version checked in matches the newly generated version.

Comment: Sounds as if the second file is an *artifact*. This shouldn't be committed to version control in the first place but generated from its source files.

Comment: General info: git does not store creation/modification timestamps for individual files. The only timestamps are in the commit itself. So if a single commit changed two files, there's no way to know which one was "changed first". For your use case that doesn't seem necessary, though. Knowing that a file was changed in a newer commit than another file would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files mentioned are already checked out you can use [`make`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/make.1.html) command to achieve what you want. The tool was designed exactly to cover the case for you:

> `make` updates a target if it depends on prerequisite files that have been modified since the target was last modified, or if the target does not exist.

Let's assume `file1` is the file used to generate `file2` only if the `file2` is older than `file1` (or does not exist). In other words, `file2` depends on `file1`. Now, the goal is to fail the CI pipeline if the `file2` is outdated with respect to `file1`. This relation can be defined as a [`rule`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rules.html). By default, all the rules are stored in a `Makefile`. In your case, the `Makefile` consists of 3 lines:

```
file2: file1
    @echo "$@ is older than $<"
    @exit 1
```

The `$@` variable will be replaced with the target name (`file2`), and the `$<` variable will be replaced with the first prerequisite (`file1`) in the echo message.

Now, when you call `make` in your pipeline, it will search for `Makefile` in the current directory and will execute it. It means if the `file1` is older than `file2` then it will do nothing (because the dependency is met). In other cases it will execute `file2` target and fail with the message accordingly.

Keep in mind `makefile` enforces TABs for indentation (it will fail if spaces are used).

Lets do some tests now:

- `file2` is up to date with respect to `file1`

```
> touch file1
> touch file2
> make
make: 'file2' is up to date.
```

- `file2` is outdated

```
> touch file2
> touch file1
> make
file2 is older than file1
make: *** [Makefile:3: file2] Error 1
```

### EDIT:

As mentioned in the comment by @phd, Git, [by design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/350417/185315), does not set files' modification dates upon checkout (all the freshly checked-out files have the same date matching the clone operation time). Since `make` relies on the modification dates it won't work as intended. However, we can fix that by setting the dates of the files (`file1`, `file2`) to the last commit dates. First, to retrieve the last commit date of the file we can use [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt) with a combination of [`--format='%ci'`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emciem) option. Then, having the last commit date of the file we set its date using [`touch -d`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html). Combining all the things together we have

```
touch -d $(git log -1 --format="%ci" -- file1) .file1
touch -d $(git log -1 --format="%ci" -- file2) .file2
```

After executing the lines we get the modification dates for the files set. The `make` should work as expected.

Comment: `make` is of no help on CI/CD pipeline because on a CI virtual host all files are freshly checked out.